# Gnome cannot login after using NoMachine remotely

Tags: rhel, gnome, remote-desktop

I was trying to set up a [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) remote desktop on a RedHat 8.6 machine.
After successfully logging in using NoMachine remotely, I could not log in to the same account physically using the laptop while connecting to the network. It always loops back to the login screen of GNOME.

Now, I can only log in to the same account remotely. But if I can log in to another account physically.

I guess it has something to do with NoMachine remote desktop, but I don't know why and how to solve this problem. Is it due to some limitations of GNOME, as I can only log in to the same account once using GUI?

Comment: I just tested this; logged out from a RasPi and a Mac, logged back in using NoMachine. When I did, I got logged in locally as well. I.e. the desktop's mirrored. Test different options in the server settings. I've set mine to be available in login screen, and acceptance not required when logging in as system user.

Comment: Thanks, Peregrino69, for checking this. Maybe I should ask RedHat about this. It is weird.